# Xbox One controller Virtual Keys

Tags: key, virtual, vk, xbox

For my uni programming exam, we have to recreate an existing game in c++ with a given small game engine. I almost finished it, and now I want to make it possible to play it with an xBox One controller for pc. However, for that I need the Virtual Key codes. Does anyone have any idea what they are or where I could possibly find them?

I've looked around on the internet and all I found was this [ActionMapping for xBox](http://www.garagegames.com/community/forums/viewthread/39932).

Referring to the link: are those KEY_BUTTON0 and KEY_BUTTON1 the key codes? And how can I use them in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more searching, I found what I needed 
[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xinput_gamepad(v=vs.85).aspx).